# Scrolling on pop up with javascript executor or selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new with web automation, currently using Selenium to learn automation web

I have a case where I need to scroll down to the bottom after select one of the available menu and set the value

Here is the pop up window

[image]

I am able to select item on the top but unable to click on the left side to scroll down after set Brand and I want to select Seller at the bottom of the left panel.
I try with javascript executor and got an null pointer, with press key PAGE_DOWN not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you need to scroll down the scrollable element containing that list of selectable options, not scrolling the entire web page.
You did not share a link to the web page you are working on and not a language you are coding with, so I can't give you a precise solution.
Working with Java I use the following method:

```
public void scrollOnElement(String css){
    JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String script = stringFormat("document.querySelector('%s').scrollDown += 250",css);
    jsExec.executeScript(css);
}
```

here `css` is a css selector for the container element I want to scroll.
Also, in your case possibly you will have to use something more smart than hardcoded 250 pixels for the scrolling height.
**UPD**
The left vertical scrollable element css locator is '#c3-mainPanel' so I think the following code should work in Python:

```
left_vertical_scrollable_css = "#c3-mainPanel"
left_vertical_scrollable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(left_vertical_scrollable_css)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", left_vertical_scrollable)
```

Comment: Link of the webpage is https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_320094 and click on All Filters button to show the pop up, I can select on item that no required scroll ie. network, operating system etc, but I can't select on item like sellers (at the bottom) or delivery items. Do you have an idea how to scroll to viewport so i can select it? I use Selenium with Python

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It should work for Python. If not there are another options.